# How to implement delete key binding in RCP 3.X

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I need to implement a delete key binding, so that when i press delete key, a selected tree node has to be deleted. I have already implemented deleting in a buttonListener, but i need to implement the same with the DEL Key as well.

***Plugin.xml***

```
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.bindings">
  <key
        commandId="org.eclipse.ui.edit.delete"
        contextId="org.eclipse.ui.contexts.dialogAndWindow"
        schemeId="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration"
        sequence="M1+DEL">  //just tried for CTRL+DEL key but i need only for DEL Key
  </key>
</extension>
```

Should i add commands? What should be in the attributes of commands?
Where should i call this action in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most plugins just use a key listener on the tree for this. Something like:

```java
treeViewer.getTree().addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
      if (event.character == SWT.DEL && event.stateMask == 0) {
         // TODO handle delete
      }
    } 
});
```

Note that Eclipse already a binding for delete:

```xml
<key
   commandId="org.eclipse.ui.edit.delete"
   sequence="DEL"
   schemeId="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration" />
```

so you may also be able to define a handler for the command `org.eclipse.ui.edit.delete` but you must make sure the handler is only active when your view/editor is active.

Comment: I have done that using Key Listener. But i want to try it this way by adding actions and commands. I don't know where to access or call this action. 
How do i activate a handler ? Can you please help ?

Comment: I can't find any examples in Eclipse using a handler for this, pretty much everything uses the key listener. You would define a `org.eclipse.ui.handlers` handler and use the `<activeWhen>` elements to define when it is active.